# how to identify an unique id in ios device?

Tags: ios, frameworks

how to identify a unique id in ios device? if I have multiple app with different developer account on same device.  How to detect both apps is on the same device?

Example: How to identify Apps A and Apps B is installed on the same device.

- different bundle id
- build with different developer account
- on the same device
- iOS 9 and above

Beside a unique id to identify device, any others solution for it?

Comment: Thankfully Apple has made this essentially impossible.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Do you just want to identify from app A that app B is also installed on the device?

Comment: Yes. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to make unique ID for each App-device , I think you can make a unique ID by generate MD5 from your bundle ID combined with UDID

But if you wanna detect if App A installed from App B, you can use URL scheme:
[Read More here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

Or you can read this: [Different ways to share data between apps — iOS](https://medium.com/@dinesh.kachhot/different-ways-to-share-data-between-apps-de75a0a46d4a)

Answer (score 0):

How to identify bundleid of any production ios app without installer file

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/identifying-bundleid-any-production-app-without-ipaapp-buyankar

- Go to https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/
- Search for required App Eg: Salesforce App , it will provide the app id in the URL
- https://apps.apple.com/in/app/salesforce/id**404249815**
- Look up with app id will give us the Json will entire details of the app. Just replace the id in the below URL

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?**id=404249815**

Eg : JSON response of Salesforce App

```
{"averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion":4.70164000000000026346924641984514892101287841796875, "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion":184073, "averageUserRating":4.70164000000000026346924641984514892101287841796875, "trackViewUrl":"https://apps.apple.com/us/app/salesforce/id404249815?uo=4", "trackContentRating":"4+", "trackId":404249815, "trackName":"Salesforce", "releaseDate":"2010-11-22T08:00:00Z", "genreIds":["6000", "6005"], "formattedPrice":"Free", "primaryGenreName":"Business", "isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled":true, "minimumOsVersion":"12.0", "sellerName":"salesforce.com", "currentVersionReleaseDate":"2020-05-11T17:59:28Z", "releaseNotes":"We update the Salesforce mobile app regularly to make it faster and more stable for you.\n\nThis version includes bug fixes and performance improvements.", "primaryGenreId":6000, "currency":"USD", "version":"224.060", "wrapperType":"software", "artistId":281826149, "artistName":"salesforce.com", "genres":["Business", "Social Networking"], "price":0.00, "description":"The new Salesforce mobile app is here!  \n \nRun your business from your phone -- faster, easier, and with AI as your sidekick. The Salesforce mobile app unlocks a whole new level of productivity, personalization, and speed.\n \nMake smart decisions with AI \nTake immediate action with intelligent views and insights into your business, powered by Einstein Analytics. Get the information you need exactly when you need it to make informed decisions from anywhere.\n \nBuild mobile experiences faster\nWith Lightning now available on mobile, building custom mobile apps is faster and easier—with clicks, not code. Mobile-optimized lightning components? Check. Dynamic and rich mobile record pages? Check. Now anyone can build amazing mobile apps fast.\n \nAccess your entire business\nThe full power of Salesforce is now available from your device. The Salesforce mobile app now includes all your favorite Lightning Apps. And the new navigation bar makes it easier than ever to get to the apps you use most.\n \nWhether you're in the office, on an airplane, or checking in from a coffee shop, the new Salesforce mobile app is your key to productivity.", **"bundleId":"com.salesforce.chatter"**, "userRatingCount":184073}]}
```

#iOS #mobileautomation #bundleid